# Insert formula for Email "To" field in InfoPath

Tags: infopath, 2013, email

I add a button into the Form.

Action:Submit

Submit Option: Email

I have a condition to send an e-mail.

If column1's value == val1 then send mail to person1

else send mail to person2.

I look into the Insert Formula for "TO" field in Email Properties.And I couldn't find out how to do it.
How can I do it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way without writing any code is to create a backer field for the email address, populate that field with a rule on column1, and then just use the backer field in the TO address directly.

See this link for specific steps:
http://www.infopathdev.com/forums/t/9306.aspx

Comment: It doesn't make any changes through the rules. So I send the mail with workflow. But why it doesn't work. I saved and published the form, made the infopath form default. NOthing worked.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to elaborate more, when you say nothing worked. All you had to do was put say personRandom field in TO section. Now set this personRandom field depending on your condition that you have mentioned.